How can one prevent any build action for a .csproj file if output directory files are newer than the source files?
Trying to get MSBuild to do nothing if the output directory DLLs (e.g. in bin\Release relative directory) are newer than all source files.
Is there an attribute available to stop a build/copy operation if the output directory is totally newer than any source (e.g. "make" kind of incremental building)?
Created all the binary files and then reran the build multiple times.  Although "Compile" actions are not executed, time-consuming copy operations still take place.

Are you using CopyToOutputDirectory="Always" on some of your files? That will break incremental builds and will cause the copy to always be performed (as you appear to describe). Use CopyToOutputDirectory="PreserveNewest" to only perform the copy if the destination file is out of date.

MSBuild supports incremental builds by default. You don't need to set attribute to make kind of incremental building. In your case, you can check if have added copy task or configured special settings.

@JonathanDodds for SDK-style .NET projects in newer versions of VS, CopyToOutputDirectory="Always" is now treated correctly and won't hurt your build times.

@ewc_visa, what kinds of projects are these? Are they SDK-style .NET projects, or legacy style (.NET Framework-era) .NET projects, or something else.

If you're using SDK-style projects, see https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/blob/main/docs/up-to-date-check.md#debugging and set your log level to "Minimal" or "Verbose". That'll show information about why VS doesn't think your projects are up-to-date. If you see a lot of copying, you might like to try out Build Acceleration if you aren't already using it. If you think there's a bug, please open an issue at that repo. Thanks!

@DrewNoakes Do you have a link to documentation, release notes, or another source for the behavior change for CopyToOutputDirectory="Always" in SDK style projects? I could really use something that I can use as a citation. Thanks

@JonathanDodds sure, here's the PR that changed it https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/pull/7963. The fix was in 17.2.

You can also just try it for yourself :)


Is there an attribute available to stop a build/copy operation if the output directory is totally newer than any source (e.g. "make" kind of incremental building)?

MSBuild supports incremental builds by default. You don't need to set attribute to make kind of incremental building.
If the output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files (i.e., the output files are newer than the input files), MSBuild will skip the target. It won't do such a copy operation.

However, if you see that time-consuming copy operations still take place, please check the following suggestions:
1.Please check if you add Copy Task in your .csproj file.If yes, set SkipUnchangedFiles to true to skip the copying of files that are unchanged between the source and destination.
For example
 <Target Name="CopyTarget" AfterTargets="Build">
    <ItemGroup>
        <FilesToCopy Include="path\to\your\files\**\*" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(FilesToCopy)" DestinationFolder="$(OutputPath)" SkipUnchangedFiles="true" />
</Target>

2.As @Jonathan said, please check if you have set CopyToOutputDirectory="Always".If yes, this will copy the file to the output directory every time you build the project, regardless of whether the file has changed.
Docs Referred:
Copy task
Common MSBuild project items
